# Como obtener id de un listado generado por un while, para ser usado en una consulta dentro de una ventana modal? usando solo HTML, PHP y javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Paso a explicar: yo genero una lista a partir de la consulta de una tabla MySQL usando un while para recorrer las filas.
cuando genero el listado muestros la información y muestro dos botones; para ello agrego un formulario con input´s de type:hidde para capturar los valores.
los dos botones son: uno para eliminar el registro (de type submit, el cual utiliza el metodo post para enviar los datos y funciona bien no tengo problema) y otro para actualizar (type es button y tiene un evento Onclick con una función que muestra una ventana modal donde esta el otro formulario), la finalidad es recuperar el ID de la consulta para cargar el formulario actualizar que se abre en una ventana modal. Les dejo el código y les sigo comentando:

```
<?php 

     include("Logicas/conexion.php");

     $slistubi = "SELECT IDUbicacion, NombreUbica, Direccion, CP, Tel FROM 
     ubicaciones WHERE IDEstado = 8";
     $resul = mysqli_query($con, $slistubi);
?>

<div class="Input-group">
    <label for="">Buscar</label>
    <input type="text" name="buscar">
</div>

<?php while ($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($resul)) {
    $idubica = $mostrar['IDUbicacion'];
    ?>
<div class="tarju">

    <div class="campo_u"><?php echo $idubica; ?></div>
    <div class="campo_u"><?php echo $mostrar['NombreUbica']; ?></div>
    <div class="campo_u"><?php echo $mostrar['Direccion']; ?></div>
    <div class="campo_u"><?php echo $mostrar['CP']; ?> </div>
    <div class="campo_u"><?php echo $mostrar['Tel']; ?></div>

    <form method="POST" action="Logicas/DeletActual.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="id_ubica" value="<?php echo   $idubica; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="nom_ubica" value="<?php echo  $mostrar['NombreUbica'] ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="dire_ubica" value="<?php echo $mostrar['Direccion'] ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="cp_ubica" value="<?php echo   $mostrar['CP'] ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="tel_ubica" value="<?php echo  $mostrar['Tel']?>">
        <button class="btntarjtdelet" name="DeletUbi" type="submit" onclick ="return ConfDelet();">Eliminar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btntarjt"  
     onclick="FubicAct();">Actualizar</button>
    </form>

     </div>

     <?php
     }

     mysqli_close($con);

    ?>

    <div class="btn-group">

    <button type="button" class="btnTks" 
    onclick="cerrarLubica();">Cerrar</button>
   </div>

 </div>`
```

Esto me Muestra correctamente la lista y no me da errores de código.

El siguiente código lo utilizo para cargar los campos de la ventana modal y el archivo se llama CargaUbicaciones.php

```
<?php 

include ("conexion.php"); 

$SupdateUbica = "SELECT IDUbicacion, NombreUbica, Direccion, CP, Tel FROM ubicaciones WHERE IDUbicacion ='$idubica'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $SupdateUbica);
$datoUbi = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$id_ubica = $datoUbi['IDUbicacion'];
$nom_ubica = $datoUbi['NombreUbica'];
$dir_ubica = $datoUbi['Direccion'];
$cp_ubica = $datoUbi['CP'];
$tel_ubica = $datoUbi['Tel'];

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Por Ultimo el formulario dentro de la ventana modal para actualizar

```
<?php
 include ("Logicas/CargaUbicaciones.php"); 

 ?>

<div class="modal" id="Modal-FActualubica">

    <div class="contentmodal">

        <form id="formUbica-act" action= "Logicas/updateUbica.php" method="Post">

    <div class="titulomenu">
        <h2>Actualización datos de Ubicación</h2>
    </div>

        <input type="" name="idubicacion" value="<?php echo $id_ubica ?>" >
    <div class="Input-group">
        <label>Nombre:</label>
        <input type="Text" name="nombreubicación" pattern="[A-Za-z ]{4,}" value="<?php echo $nom_ubica ?>" >
    </div>

    <div class="Input-group">
        <label>Dirección:</label>
        <input type="text" name="direccionUbica" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9 /-]{4,}" value="<?php echo $dir_ubica ?>">
    </div>

    <div class="Input-group">
        <label >Cod-Postal:</label>
        <input type="text" name="cpUbica" pattern="[0-9]{4,}" value="<?php echo $cp_ubica ?>">
    </div>

    <div class="Input-group">
        <label>Telefono:</label>
        <input type="text" name="telUbica" pattern="[0-9 -]{10,12}" value="<?php echo $tel_ubica ?>">
    </div>

    <?php include("Opciones/OptionUbica.php"); ?>

    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type= "submit" class="btnTks" name="Act_Ubica">Guardar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btnTks" onclick="cerrarActUbica();">Cerrar</button>
    </div>

</form>

    </div>
</div>
```

así como esta siempre me devuelve el ultimo registro (el while va pisando la variable en cada vuelta) es decir siempre que haga click en cualquier botón actualizar de la lista me muestra la ventana modal con el ultimo registro de la tabla. Lo que quiero es, que cada vez que se presione sobre el botón actualizar me muestre la ventana modal con la información correspondiente a ese registro.
por ultimo les dejo los escript de los botones (por si acaso)

boton actualizar:

```
function FubicAct(){
    var modal = document.getElementById("Modal-FActualubica");

    modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

boton eliminar:

```
function ConfDelet(){


    if (confirm("Esta seguro de eliminar el Registro?")) {

        return true;
    }
        return false;
}
```

Espero haber sido lo suficientemente claro y sino los iré aclarando a medida que surjan.
desde ya muchas gracias.

P/D: No uso Bootstrap ni Jquery ni ajax, solo javascript.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: "P/D: No uso Bootstrap ni Jquery ni ajax, solo javascript." aqui esta el problema, por que tratas de mostrar un modal, que ya esta cargado con el ultimo registro de tu bucle, ya que segun la asignacion lo haces de esa forma, y lo intentas llamar de forma sincrona, lo cual no es posible, lamentablemente. La unica opcion sería que le pasaras cada valor que vayas a mostrar en el modal cuando hace click en el boton actualizar.

Comment: podrías mostrarme como hacerlo, si no es mucha molestia? para darme una idea...